Java read mainframe file lines for each record and store in list
I am trying to read a mainframe file to write to XML in java. I expect to get my output data as below XML sample. Currently, I get empty values for FUND, FUNDID,etc. I am trying to store the previous line value and print those in next line till new fund criteria is met. Looking to Help in something like if fund matched in new line = record started, read next lines for matching criteria and then print the list of records. then if again fund matched start new record.
AMFDS 2045 TDRF R 1XA 100.0%     5,634.40        376.91         251.07            .00            .00       6,260.93-M          .00
                                                                                                           1.45-M

I need to print the output as
<ACTIVITY>
<FUND><![CDATA[AMFDS 2045 TDRF R]]></FUND>
<FUND_ID><![CDATA[1X]]></FUND_ID>
<SOURCE><![CDATA[A]]></SOURCE>
<MIXPERCENTAGE><![CDATA[100.0%]]></MIXPERCENTAGE>
<YTD><![CDATA[376.91]]></YTD>
<BALANCE><![CDATA[6,260.93]]></BALANCE>
</ACTIVITY>
<ACTIVITY>
<FUND><![CDATA[AMFDS 2045 TDRF R]]></FUND>
<FUND_ID><![CDATA[1X]]></FUND_ID>
<SOURCE><![CDATA[A]]></SOURCE>
<MIXPERCENTAGE><![CDATA[100.0%]]></MIXPERCENTAGE>
<YTD><![CDATA[376.91]]></YTD>
<BALANCE><![CDATA[1.45]]></BALANCE>
</ACTIVITY>

 
private void processFundRecords(Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier, Map<String, List<String>> recordMap){
        List<String> fundLines = new ArrayList<>();
        streamSupplier.get().forEach(line -> {
                    if (isFund(streamSupplier))
            {
                // If it's the start of a new fund, process the previous fund lines
                if (!fundLines.isEmpty()) {
                    processFundData((Supplier<Stream<String>>) fundLines, recordMap);
                    fundLines.clear(); // Reset the fund lines
                }
                fundLines.add(line); // Start a new fund record
            } else if (isPartOfSameFundRecord(streamSupplier) || line.startsWith("LOAN")) {
                fundLines.add(line); // Add to the current fund record
            }
        });
                    // Process any remaining fund lines
        if (!fundLines.isEmpty()) {
            processFundData((Supplier<Stream<String>>) fundLines, recordMap);
        }
    }

    private boolean ignoreLines(Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier) {
        return streamSupplier.get().anyMatch(line ->
                line.startsWith("** TOTAL") ||
                        line.startsWith("***** INVESTMENTS") ||
                        line.startsWith("***** SOURCES")
        );
    }

    private void processFundData(Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier, Map<String, List<String>> recordMap) {
        if (streamSupplier.get().allMatch(s -> s.length() == 0)) {
            return;
        }
        if(!ignoreLines(streamSupplier)) {
            recordMap.put(FUND, streamSupplier.get()
                    .map(s -> s.substring(0, 17).trim())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            recordMap.put(FUNDID, streamSupplier.get()
                    .map(s -> s.substring(18, 20).trim())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            recordMap.put(SOURCE, streamSupplier.get()
                    .map(s -> s.substring(20, 21).trim())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            recordMap.put(MIXPERCENTAGE,
                    streamSupplier.get().map(s -> s.substring(22, 28).trim())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            recordMap.put(YTD, streamSupplier.get().map(s -> s.substring(43, 55).trim())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            recordMap.put(MBALANCE, streamSupplier.get()
                    .filter(s -> s.length() > 115 && s.substring(115, 117).contains("-M"))
                    .map(s -> s.substring(103, 115).trim())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
}

 
if (isPartOfSameFundRecord(streamSupplier)) {
                    fundFound = true;
                    activityKeyBucketMap = initializeNewMap(activityKeyBucketList);
                    processFundData(streamSupplier, activityKeyBucketMap);

                    //System.out.println("#### FUND ###");
                }


You didn’t ask a question. But 1) you can’t cast a collection to supplier (of stream) and expect it to work. But 2) there is no point in shoehorning streams into this code. Your code would be simpler and more readable if it just accepted collections as input and used ordinary loops.

Trying my luck on this one:

Create a method that will simplify handling each line's data and make it more readable
Declare a clear method to detect when a new fund begins.
Once you detect a new fund, you should accumulate lines until the next fund starts.
Write the formatted data to an XML structure.

Here's an improvement that could possibly work for you:


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FundProcessor {

    private static final String FUND = "FUND";
    private static final String FUND_ID = "FUND_ID";
    private static final String SOURCE = "SOURCE";
    private static final String MIX_PERCENTAGE = "MIXPERCENTAGE";
    private static final String YTD = "YTD";
    private static final String BALANCE = "BALANCE";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Assuming this is where you read lines from a file or another source
        Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> Stream.of(
                "AMFDS 2045 TDRF R 1XA 100.0%     5,634.40        376.91         251.07"
                // Add more lines as needed for testing
        );

        List<String> records = processRecords(streamSupplier);
        records.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<String> processRecords(Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier) {
        List<String> fundLines = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> outputXml = new ArrayList<>();

        streamSupplier.get().forEach(line -> {
            if (isNewFund(line)) {
                if (!fundLines.isEmpty()) {
                    outputXml.add(processFundData(fundLines));
                    fundLines.clear();
                }
            }
            fundLines.add(line);
        });

        if (!fundLines.isEmpty()) {
            outputXml.add(processFundData(fundLines));
        }

        return outputXml;
    }

    private static boolean isNewFund(String line) {
        // Implement your logic to determine if the line starts a new fund
        return line.matches(".*\\d+XA.*");  // Example regex, adjust according to actual criteria
    }

    private static String processFundData(List<String> fundLines) {
        // Extract data from the first line or further lines as needed
        String firstLine = fundLines.get(0);
        String fund = firstLine.substring(0, 17).trim();
        String fundId = firstLine.substring(18, 20).trim();
        String source = firstLine.substring(20, 21).trim();
        String mixPercentage = firstLine.substring(21, 28).trim();
        String ytd = firstLine.substring(43, 50).trim();
        String balance = firstLine.substring(57, 65).trim().replace(",", "");

        return String.format("<ACTIVITY>\n<FUND><![CDATA[%s]]></FUND>\n<FUND_ID><![CDATA[%s]]></FUND_ID>\n<SOURCE><![CDATA[%s]]></SOURCE>\n<MIXPERCENTAGE><![CDATA[%s]]></MIXPERCENTAGE>\n<YTD><![CDATA[%s]]></YTD>\n<BALANCE><![CDATA[%s]]></BALANCE>\n</ACTIVITY>", fund, fundId, source, mixPercentage, ytd, balance);
    }
}



You can edit to how it suits you. I hope it helps!
